# Using Exception Cascade in JavaScript with Modules and Promises?

Tags: javascript, exception, error-handling, es6-promise, es6-modules

In some packages I've coded in PHP, I generally tell the functions which are responsible for the execution of some process X to throw an Exception at some point of failure, without catching the exception within the function of the process X itself. Something like:

```
function execute_process_x() {

  // Do Task X, and throw Exception if it fails
  if(!$successful) {
    throw new Exception('Operation X failed!');
  }

}
```

Within the outermost controller call, I then call all of the callbacks which execute the  processes to be completed for that controller call, and wrap these calls to the process callbacks within a try-catch. Main thought is to always be able to handle the errors on a controller-specific level, which makes most sense according to my design. So you would then for example have sth like:

```
function controller_call(){

  try{

    execute_process_x();
    execute_process_y();
    execute_process_z();

  } catch( Exception $e ) {

    // Controller-specific error handling, in this case of controller_call, simply exit;
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit();

  }
}
```

I would now like to ideally implement a similar thing in javascript, using [native Modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules), and, this I guess is the main problem, [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).

I've tried to implement this by for example creating a first JavaScript module `request.js` that has some different callbacks that I repetitively call to execute requests to my server, using the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch). Something like:

```
// request.js:

function post_request(data) {

    return fetch(
        'https://example.org/api/v1/users',
        {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          mode: 'same-origin',
          body: data
        } 
    ).then((response) => {

            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('"OK" property of response is not "true" !');
            }

            // Verify that the content type is correct before proceeding
            const contentType = response.headers.get('content-type');
            if (!contentType || !contentType.includes('application/json')) {
                throw new TypeError("Content Type 'application/json' could not be verified!");
            }

            // Verify server response of 200
            if (response.status !== 200) {
                throw new Error('Unexpected server response');
            }

            // Parse obtained result data to Js object
            return response.json();

        })
        .then((data) => {

            // Return js object if everything's alright
            return data;

        })
        .catch((error) => {

            // Alert that an error occurred in case of any error, and return false
            throw new Error(error);

        });

}

export {post_request}
```

I'm then trying to use the main script below, sth like:

```
main.js:

import {post_request} from './request.js'

function controller_call() {

  try {
    
    post_request({hello: "there"});

    console.log("execution did not interrupt!");
    
  } catch(e) {

    alert(e.message);

  }

}
```

When doing this and the call to `post_request()` within `main.js` fails, I never get an alert, but a logged Uncaught Exception of the error message caught in `request.js`. Even worse, the script `main.js` keeps executing, as I can see `execution did not interrupt` being logged in the console.

How can I actually reach the Exception pattern I'm looking for, using esmodules and promises?

Comment: that's because throwing an error in a promise chain simply rejects the promise - what you should look at is `async`/`await` which is commonly used with `try`/`catch` when dealing with Promises

Comment: I would like to post the solution that I found thanks to your comment and the helpful links linked above. But my question got closed as duplicate, while none of the links above and none of the existing pages I could find in this forum even mention the use of `async`/`await` with `try`/`catch` **combined** with native javascript modules and the fetch API, having at least 2 promise resolutions in its chain (one to fetch the data, one to `.json()`). In my opinion these differences are not negligible, at least they confused me. I'd just like to post my answer if anyone drops into the same problem.